# Requiring login for only one section of Shiny app

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app in which the main app page needs to be public, but  downloading data files will require authentication via login. Ideally, users could select the download parameters (which variables they want included, etc) and are not asked to sign in until they actually click the "Download" button.

Every question I've seen on this topic discusses how to make different app versions available based on login credentials, but those all require an initial login, so they are not applicable.

My thinking is to create two separate apps, with the "Download" button linking to the second app. However, this would need to "remember" download request inputs entered in the first app. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553542/using-an-input-from-a-shiny-app-in-another-shiny-app) is similar, but I am not using Rmarkdown.

Questions I've seen that address how to link Shiny apps usually conclude that you should separate the source code and call everything from another file (making it a single app), but shinyapps.io apps can only [require authentication](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shinyapps-io-authentication-authorization/) at a the level of the entire app, so combining them wouldn't work.

So I suppose I am looking for advice on either of the following options:

1) Restricting authentication to one section of the app. Right now, my likely authorization tool for an open-source Shiny Server (not set up yet) will be auth0, but if this partial-authentication is doable with Shiny Server Pro then my organization might be willing to upgrade to Pro.

2) Feeding input from one app (the download parameters) to another app (which asks for login info, then returns the download file).

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write the login-logic yourself. Here is a simple illustration how this can be done with `renderUI`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("public area", "Eveyone can see this!"),
    tabPanel("login area", uiOutput("login_area"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  logged_in = reactiveVal(FALSE)

  output$logged_in <- renderUI({"you are logged in"})

  output$not_logged_in <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      "you are not logged in",
      actionButton("login", "Log me in!")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$login, logged_in(TRUE))

  output$login_area <- renderUI({
    if (logged_in())
      uiOutput("logged_in")
    else
      uiOutput("not_logged_in")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```